# react-native-batch not building android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am using react 17 and react-native 0.68.2 and [react-native-batch](https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-batch-push) not building on android. I have done all the setup for android and iOS part (editing all build.gradle etc.) I didn't implemented anything yet of this library. This give me an error while building on fresh install.

It gives me this error:

```
/Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/packages/native-client/node_modules/@bam.tech/react-native-batch/android/src/main/java/tech/bam/RNBatchPush/RNUtils.java:113: error: no suitable method found for put(String,URI)
                batchEventData.put(key, URI.create(valueMap.getString("value")));
                              ^
    method BatchEventData.put(String,String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; URI cannot be converted to String)
    method BatchEventData.put(String,float) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; URI cannot be converted to float)
    method BatchEventData.put(String,double) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; URI cannot be converted to double)
    method BatchEventData.put(String,int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; URI cannot be converted to int)
    method BatchEventData.put(String,long) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; URI cannot be converted to long)
    method BatchEventData.put(String,boolean) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; URI cannot be converted to boolean)
    method BatchEventData.put(String,Date) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; URI cannot be converted to Date)
/Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/packages/native-client/node_modules/@bam.tech/react-native-batch/android/src/main/java/tech/bam/RNBatchPush/RNBatchModule.java:529: error: no suitable method found for setAttribute(String,URI)
                editor.setAttribute(key, URI.create(url));
                      ^
    method BatchUserDataEditor.setAttribute(String,long) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; URI cannot be converted to long)
    method BatchUserDataEditor.setAttribute(String,double) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; URI cannot be converted to double)
    method BatchUserDataEditor.setAttribute(String,boolean) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; URI cannot be converted to boolean)
    method BatchUserDataEditor.setAttribute(String,Date) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; URI cannot be converted to Date)
    method BatchUserDataEditor.setAttribute(String,String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; URI cannot be converted to String)
```

If someone have already faced this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve the issue with the help of Arnaud-roland: https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-batch-push/issues/83

And in `build.gradle` you need to upgrade the version of `batchSdkVersion`:

```
ext {
    batchSdkVersion = '1.19+'
}
```